# How to display repeated data only once

Tags: php, loops

Working in php how can the following be achieved:

I have a DB table containing users and corresponding objects.

Table:

```
ID    User        Object
1     Billy       Phone
2     Dwayne      DVD
3     D'Angelo    DVD
4     Billy       Phone
5     Dwayne      DVD
6     D'Angelo    Truck
7     Billy       Football
8     D'Angelo    DVD
```

The table has some rows which contain the same user and object combination repeated e.g ID 1 and 4, and ID 3 and 8.
When a particular user is logged in, I would like to cycle through the table and display on the page.
 
(only related to the particular user who is logged in) the user and the object for each user-object combination only once, so that in the above example "Billy and Phone" and "D'Angelo and DVD" do not repeat and the table below becomes
what is shown below.

I can't think which loop to use.

When Billy logs in:

```
ID    User        Object
1     Billy       Phone
2     Billy       Football
```

When D'Angelo logs in:

```
ID    User        Object
1     D'Angelo    DVD
2     D'Angleo    Truck
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: @figs I have but it doesn't work and is silly

Comment: make sure its ordered by the field you want to suppress, keep track of last value, if new value same as last display a blank....very simple

Comment: try `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT user,object FROM table where user like '<name>'
```

Comment: You should explain this SQL statement and why/how it addresses the issue raised in the posted question.